# Nokogiri unable to get by CSS class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the bio of a Twitter profile using Nokogiri, and have tried everything to get an element using CSS. The follow returns an empty string:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://twitter.com/n"))
puts doc.css('.ProfileHeaderCard-bio').text
```

However, if I try to output everything in the body, the content is indeed there. So the following works:

```
puts doc.css('body').text
```

But selecting by a CSS class fails: `puts doc.css('.ProfileHeaderCard-bio').text`

Any idea why?

---

**Update:**

Apparently Twitter changes CSS classes after load, so a browser's source code does something entirely different than what `wget` showed.

Comment: I checked the twitter link and there is no class called `.ProfileHeaderCard-bio`. I believe the css class changed. If you can indeed find it in the html, please add the HTML snippet as well

Comment: It turns out twitter dynamically changes all the classes in order to prevent scraping.

Comment: Please consider using twitter api instead. This is probably the best way to consume this information.

Comment: @anbiniyar Only problem with the API is that I can't get the profile data for someone unless they come to the site and do an Oauth themselves.

Comment: This is a very common problem when dealing with pages that use dynamic HTML. JavaScript can do things inside a browser, that a parser like Nokogiri can't. Nokogiri parses the HTML, it doesn't interpret and run JavaScript. Look at the [Watir](http://watir.com/) project for a way around this.

Comment: Also, you can see what the HTML looks like by turning off the JavaScript in your browser and (re)loading the page. I do that occasionally when I know the document is dynamic and want to see what it'd look like before the adjustments happen.